# switch button - Click is working but sliding switch is not working in android

Tags: android

This is my code snippet for switch button.

```
productChildViewHolder.switchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Utility.displayToast("here");
                //Is the switch is on?
                boolean on = ((Switch) v).isChecked();
                if (on) {
                    productVariant.setAvailable(1);
                } else {
                    productVariant.setAvailable(0);
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("Type", "UPDATE_AVAILABLE");
                    jsonObject.put("ProductID", productVariant.getProductID());
                    jsonObject.put("VariantID", productVariant.getVariantID());
                    jsonObject.put("Available", productVariant.getAvailable());
                    new UpdateProductVariantTask().execute(jsonObject.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

For me click is working as expected. and even click in toggling the button. But sliding just toggle it, but doesn't hit the function.

How to make slide and click work in same way for switch button?

Comment: What about if you try `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: If i use this function, in recycler-view it i hitting when scroll up/down. as i am setting one filed based on this value.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `setOnClickListener` to `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.
And inside your listener check if `buttonView.isPressed()` to be sure it was pressed by userer (and not changed by the framework detection)

**Code:**

```
productChildViewHolder.switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if(buttonView.isPressed() && isChecked){
                //Your code here
                }
            }
        });
```

**Why is this happening -**

The ViewHolder pattern renders the "base" view and inflate the changes for better performance.
 Unfortunately implemented very poorly by android developers and causes many weird problems which are very hard to detect.

**What our options?**

If possible - use a simple list view.
If the demand is more complicated and will cause performance issues look for open source library [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Must-Have-Libraries#listview).

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. :)

Comment: hey i observed some unusual behavior with this code. event is not getting detected always. Any clue why is that so??

Comment: In general , the viewHolder pattern suppose to be best practice but was purely implemented and causes a lot of "strange" problems, my recommendation is not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
     productChildViewHolder.switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                productVariant.setAvailable(1);
            } else {
                productVariant.setAvailable(0);
            }
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("Type", "UPDATE_AVAILABLE");
                jsonObject.put("ProductID", productVariant.getProductID());
                jsonObject.put("VariantID", productVariant.getVariantID());
                jsonObject.put("Available", productVariant.getAvailable());
                new UpdateProductVariantTask().execute(jsonObject.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope I have helped you.
Good luck